# Task group in pipeline not updating after modifying

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have task group which was modified and additional step was added inside task group. We awaiting that this task group will be be simultaneously updated on all pipelines which used.

But Old task on all pipelines

Right now we deleting old task and adding new one but old one shouldn't exist.

Comment: Are you talking about old *releases* (i.e. discrete instances of a release pipeline)? Because updating a task group does not update your old releases, it only applies to *new* releases created after the task group is updated.

Comment: @Ant-cpu Do you mean that after the task group is updated, the pipeline does not run the updated tasks?